# ¿Como agregar una excepcion de errores en un procedimiento almacenado? CODIGO MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, stored-procedure, excepciones

**Problema: Necesito agregar una excepción de errores a este procedimiento almacenado, lo ejecuto y me da error, no se si pudieran corregir, TRY CATCH DE SQL A MYSQL. Gracias**

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_RegistrarCandidato(
p_NombresCompleto varchar(100),
p_Mensaje varchar(100),
p_IdEleccion int,
p_IdUsuarioRegistro int,
out p_Resultado int)

begin
SET p_Resultado = 0;

begin try

insert into CANDIDATOS
         (NombresCompleto,Mensaje,
          IdEleccion,IdUsuarioRegistro,
          Activo,FechaRegistro,RutaImagen) 
values (p_NombresCompleto,p_Mensaje,
        p_IdEleccion,p_IdUsuarioRegistro,
        1,now(3),'');

    SET p_Resultado  = Last_insert_id();

end;

try
begin catch
    SET p_Resultado = 0;
end; 
catch

end;
 //

DELIMITER ;
```

Ese es el codigo donde dice "DECLARE CONTINUE..", esa línea me causa error, esta mal aplicada creo y da error al ejecutar el código completo. A partir de `last insert`, no sé qué hacer con eso. Si ahí pudiera corregirlo, gracias.

Comment: Estás seguro de que `mysql` tiene bloque try/catch?? Juraría que no lo tenía... aunque hace ya un tiempo que no utilizo mysql, pero tampoco encontré nada en la documentación de mysql 8.0. Tal vez no busqué lo suficiente a fondo, pero debería ser fácil de encontrar algo así

Comment: La pregunta es con qué comparaste el código. Si sigues migrando desde SQL server como en la pregunta anterior, tienes que indicarlo en cada pregunta donde estés haciendo lo mismo para poder ayudarte. En este caso, estás intentando usar algo de T-SQL que no existe en mysql

Comment: Si disculpen si en efecto sigo migrando codigo de SQL a MYSQL, como transformaria en todo caso el TRY/CATCH o como se aplicaría un try catch en el codigo que les presente.

Comment: **SQL** a secas es una cosa, **SQL Server** es otra :) PHPMyAdmin es una herramienta, así que no tiene algo que ver en esta pregunta. Además, pulsa en [edit] y especifica cuál es el problema en concreto: _¿cuál es el error?_

Comment: Ya lo edite un poco mejor, espero que ahora si se me comprenda.El problema es que nose ¿como cambiar el try catch por otra funcion en MYSQL?, porque ese TRY CATCH es de SQL Eso se debe a que estoy migrando codigo de SQL a MYSQL y me falta el TRY que me tira error y no puedo por ende crear el procedimiento Registrar candidato.

Comment: No es que sea un problema en el try catch, sino que estás buscando una sintaxis equivalente en MySQL para el try catch de T-SQL / **SQL SERVER** (con énfasis, porque SQL a secas es el estándar). Sucede básicamente lo que @Alfabravo mencionó en su comentario. Dale un título más descriptivo a tu pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo Solucionado.

Comment: @jojojo Si encontraste la solución a tu problema, ponlo en la zona de respuestas y [acéptala](/help/accepted-answer) cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo. Lee [answer], y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ACTUALIZO Código corregido por mi mismo queda así y se creo correctamente el procedimiento con la excepción de errores:**

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_RegistrarCandidato 
(p_NombresCompleto varchar(100), p_Mensaje varchar(100), p_IdEleccion 
 int, p_IdUsuarioRegistro int, out p_Resultado int ) 

begin 
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION 
SET p_Resultado = 0; 

INSERT INTO CANDIDATOS
 (NombresCompleto,Mensaje,
 IdEleccion,IdUsuarioRegistro,Activo
 ,FechaRegistro,RutaImagen) 
values 
 (p_NombresCompleto,p_Mensaje,
 p_IdEleccion,p_IdUsuarioRegistro,
 1,now(3),''); 

SET p_Resultado = Last_insert_id(); 

 end;

//DELIMITER ;
```